# Proximity Map from Line Shapefile (Line to Raster)

Tags: qgis, proximity, rasterization

I have this cycling route and I need a proximity map that shows the proximity to this route:

[image: THE CYCLING ROUTE]

I have the route as line shape, and I turned it into raster (using vector to raster). Following this exact tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lGeDskzrdY&ab_channel=OpenSourceRemoteSensing%26GIS

Then, I get the raster file like this (i zoom in to show details);

[image: RASTERIZED ROUTE LAYER]

Then I finally use the Proximity (Raster Distance) tool to produce the final map but I only get a full black cover..

[image: Proximity map]

I just want a simple proximity map that shows the distance from this route.

Where am I doing wrong?

As I followed the linked tutorial these are the steps for the rasterization:

[image: adding value 0 to attribute table]

[image: adding these values to the tool]

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you layer is in a projected coordinate system so the units arent in degrees.
2. Rasterize (vector to raster). `Fixed value to burn = 1`, set a reasonable resolution. My route is ~90 km from north to south so I use 100 m so the rasterization is quick.
3. Proximity (rasterdistance). `Set A list of pixel values.... = 1`

[image]
[image]